# Display a computed observable in a text input

Tags: knockout.js, computed-observable

Why does the text `input` in my example code simply show the numeric value entered into it, rather than the formatted value with a "`$`"?

```js
function MyViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    this.price = ko.observable(25.99);

    this.formattedPrice = ko.computed({
        read: function () {
            return "$" + self.price().toFixed(2);
        },
        write: function (value) {
            // Strip out unwanted characters, parse as float, then write the raw data back to the underlying "price" observable
            value = parseFloat(value.replace(/[^\.\d]/g, ""));
            self.price(isNaN(value) ? 0 : value); // Write to underlying storage
        },
        owner: self
    });
}

ko.applyBindings(new MyViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<p>Price: <input data-bind="value: formattedPrice" /></p>
```

Comment: It works perfectly fine when I am running your code. Edited question with sinppet.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is good.

Knockout calls the `write` method when the value changes - this normally occurs when the focus leaves the textbox. Try changing the value then pressing tab - you should see the displayed value change.

If you want to update the display for each keypress you could try the [textInput binding][1], however this is not recommended as it tends to conflict with the typing process. Try

[1]: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/textinput-binding.html "textInput binding", but for a field like this you might find it unsuitable as it changes as you type.